# How to cite a chapter in an edited book with a unique translator for that chapter using Chicago Style?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I'm using Chicago Style 17th edition, author-date system. I'm trying to cite a chapter from an edited book, but every chapter has a different translator.

Chicago Manual says that for edited books, the format is:

Author Surname, First Name. Year. "Title of Chapter." In *Book Title*, edited by Editor First Name Surname, page range of chapter. Place of Publication: Publisher.

But where do I include the translator who is not the translator of the whole book but only that chapter?

Answer (score 1):

Chicago Manual of Style Online has a [Q&A addressing this question](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0058.html):

> **Q.** I’m trying to complete a bibliographic entry for a chapter in a multiauthor book. The chapter was translated from Korean into English. (The rest of the chapters have many various other translators.) How would I cite it? Where do I put the translation credit in the Chicago style citation? After the article title or after the book title?
>
> **A.** When you have a special instance not covered in CMOS, fish around until you see something similar and follow the pattern. You might base your citation on CMOS 14.104 (“Editor or translator in addition to author”), 14.107 (“Contribution to a multiauthor book”), and 14.122 (“Authors and editors of multivolume works”). You don’t want to imply that the translator of the chapter was the translator of the entire book, so put the translator’s name after the chapter title:
>
> 13. Author’s Name, “Chapter Title,” trans. Translator’s Name, in *Name of Multiauthor Book*, ed. Editors’ Names (Place: Publisher, Date), page numbers.

Where you place the year/date of publication might change between different editions of the style guide, but the logic of placing the translator's name next to the chapter title is unlikely to change.

Comment: So in bibliography format, it's supposed to be like this? Author Surname, First Name. Year. "Title of Chapter." Translated by Translator First Name Surname. In Book Title, edited by Editor First Name Surname, page range of chapter. Place of Publication: Publisher.

Comment: @JohnSmith That looks good to me, based on the format in your original post.